# Равны ли два pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как проверить, что данные в двух pandas.DataFrame совпадают?

Comment: [`equals()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) - пройдите по ссылке, там есть примеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [`equals()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html), можно сравнить данные в двух датафреймах.

Пример из документации:

```
In [93]: df = pd.DataFrame({1: [10], 2: [20]})                                                     

In [94]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [10], 2: [20]})                                                    

In [95]: df                                                                                        
Out[95]: 
    1   2
0  10  20

In [96]: df2                                                                                       
Out[96]: 
    1   2
0  10  20

In [97]: df.equals(df2)                                                                            
Out[97]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно преобразовать датафрейм в список и сравнить списки. Списки python сравнивать умеет

```py
import pandas as pd
# пример входных данных
a = [{'b':[1, 2, 3], 'c':23, 1:['hello',(1,2)]}]
b = [{'b':[1, 2, 3], 'c':23, 1:['hello',(1,2)]}]
c = [{'b':[1, 2, 3], 'c':23}]

df_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b)
df_c = pd.DataFrame(c)

print (df_a.to_dict() == df_b.to_dict())
print (df_a.to_dict() == df_c.to_dict())
print (df_b.to_dict() == df_c.to_dict())
```

Результат:

```
True
False
False
```